# Conditional way for a column to take the previous value of itself without resorting to a for loop

Tags: pandas

Basically I want to create a new column which replicates the last different value of another column.

I tried this but doesn't work.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

column1=  [1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2 ]
data = pd.DataFrame(column1, columns =['column1'])

data['column2'] =  np.where(data['column1'] != data['column1'].shift(1),  data['column1'].shift(1),data['column2'].shift(1))
```

Also tried this:

```
data['column2'] = [data['column2'].shift(1) if x != data['column1'].shift(1) else    data['column1'].shift(1) for x in data['column1']]
```

Desired output is as follows:

```
column1,column2
1,
2,1
2,1
2,1
3,2
3,2
3,2
3,2
3,2
3,2
2,3
2,3
2,3
2,3
```

Oh and while I'm sure I can do this with a for loop, I'm interested in finding a way to get this done without a loop.

Thanks

Edit: This method gets closer, but I ned to run these two lines of code once at a time, so it's extremely impractical.

```
data.loc[data['column1'] != data['column1'].shift(1), 'column2'] = data['column1'].shift(1)
data.loc[data['column1'] == data['column1'].shift(1), 'column2'] = data['column2'].shift(1)
```

Comment: It's right there. Row by row, if the current value != prior value of column1, just grab the prior value of column1. If current value == prior value of column1, just grab the prior value of column2.

Comment: @anky_91 Column 2 is the output desired I guess

Comment: Indeed, column2 is a newly created one. Take a look at the new code I found... it does the trick, but not quite so because I have to run it many times until it populates column2, which is obviously insane.

Comment: @NahuelPatiño I wonder if there is a way without `for` loop, since the new output depends on the previous and current index of column1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `shift` and groupby on custom groupID `s` and transform `first`

```
s = data.column1.diff().ne(0).cumsum()
data['column2'] = data.shift().groupby(s).column1.transform('first')

Out[374]:
    column1  column2
0         1      NaN
1         2      1.0
2         2      1.0
3         2      1.0
4         3      2.0
5         3      2.0
6         3      2.0
7         3      2.0
8         3      2.0
9         3      2.0
10        2      3.0
11        2      3.0
12        2      3.0
13        2      3.0
```

Comment: should be faster than apply without a doubt. Nice logic :)

Answer (score 1):

This works for your specific example

```
data['column2'] = data.diff(1).apply(lambda r: data.loc[r.name - 1, 'column1'] if abs(r.column1) == 1 else None, axis=1).ffill()
```

How fast it is?

```
%%timeit
data.diff(1).apply(lambda r: data.loc[r.name - 1, 'column1'] if abs(r.column1) == 1 else None, axis=1).ffill()
1.41 ms ± 14.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%%timeit
s = data.column1.diff().ne(0).cumsum()
data.shift().groupby(s).column1.transform('first')
2.36 ms ± 116 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: could you %timeit on big dataframe such as  on `data1` where `data1 = pd.concat([data]*1000, ignore_index=True)` ?

Comment: expanding the column to [1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2 ]*1000, takes 322 ms ± 10.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Comment: how does it compare against groupby transform solution? is it faster than groupby transform solution on big dataframe?

Comment: your solution is actually way faster on a large dataset: 3.52 ms ± 104 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Comment: yeah, I also just finished my `%timeit`. The `apply` solution is almost 100x slower on big dataframe. I know `apply` is slow. However, I don't expect that much :)

Answer (score 0):

Extremely slow 'solution' I just found

```
data['column2'] =np.NaN

    nacount=1
    nacount2=0
    while nacount != nacount2:
        nacount = data['column2'].isna().sum()
        data.loc[data['column1'] != data['column1'].shift(1), 'column2'] = data['column1'].shift(1)
        data.loc[data['column1'] == data['column1'].shift(1), 'column2'] = data['column2'].shift(1)
        nacount2 = data['column2'].isna().sum()
```

I'm not happy with it, excel does this formula faster.